# Trouble with Angular Component in Tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-components, angular7

I'm reading Angular in Action from Manning. Chapter 2 shows me how to write my first component but the example is outdated. I can't figure out how to update it. I'm using Angular CLI version 7.1.3.

Angular CLI generates this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-summary',
    templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.scss']
})
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

The book assumes that Angular CLI will generate this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'summary',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html'
})
export class SummaryComponent {
  @Input();
}
```

What is the difference between `@Input` and `OnInit`? How does a person take an input example and translate it into the "OnInit" way of doing things?

Comment: Yes, I tried the message board the publisher provided for the book.  No one home.

Comment: I just checked the book. Page 42 first line is: @Input() stock: any;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Input` and `ngOnInit` are two different directives and do not conflict or replace each other.

You can quite easily (manually) add `@Input` to the generated component and continue as per the book. Just ignore the `ngOnInit` for now until you learn to use it. It won't hurt to just leave it there.

If you want to know what `ngOnInit` does, look [here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

Also notice, if your example deals with the styles, then the CLI  has generated `sccs` but the book has `css`. `sccs` should technically take all `css` and should just work.

Answer (score 2):

`@Input()` is a decorator that adds metadata to the class that makes the property, *which will be written next to it*, **available for data-binding**.

`ngOnInit()` is a **lifecycle hook** that Angular calls shortly after creating the component.

Both still exist in the current version of Angular but do not have utility if they are empty *(same for the `constructor()` method)* so you can replace all your code by:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-summary',
    templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.scss']
})

export class SummaryComponent  {

}
```

You'll always be able to add them whenever you want.

Answer (score 1):

`@Input` is a decorator. It allows you to mark a field as an input argument. You can, for example, pass an argument from a parent component to a child component.

`OnInit` is an interface. It allows you to handle additional initialization tasks under `ngOnInit` method, which occurs at component creation.